# Finding ratio in finite geometric sum with capped value for summed terms

Tags: summation, roots

At my work, we need to send out emails to large number of people on an irregular basis. Due to the nature of bulk email sending, we need to start out our campaigns small and increase the number of emails being sent per day up to some maximum number until all emails have been sent. I have been working on trying to figure out the best growth ratio for the volume of emails being sent out in a single day based on some starting conditions and the timeframe that I'd like to complete them within. I have a working solution for cases where there is no need to limit the total volume to be sent in a day. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to expand this to include a cap and thought that somebody here might be able to help.

Here's what I have so far.

- $V$ = total volume of emails to send
- $v_0$ = number of emails to send on day 1
- $d$ = number of days to complete send in
- $r$ = ratio to increase volume by each day (the unknown that I'm searching for)

$$V = \sum_{n=1}^d v_0 r^{n-1} = v_0 \frac{1 - r^d}{1 - r} $$

I'm trying to solve this for $r$, the other values being known, so I simplified it to the following formula that I need to find the zeros for.

$$f(r) = v_0 r^d - V r + V - v_0$$

To find the lowest zero greater than 1, I found the first and second derivatives with respect to $r$ and use [Halley's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method).

$$f'(r) = d v_0 r^{d-1} - V$$

$$f''(r) = d (d-1) v_0 r^{d-2}$$

This all works well and I am able to use this to find an appropriate ratio that will complete my email campaigns in exactly $d$ days with as slow an increase as possible. However, the real world involves one last wrinkle that I'm having trouble adding to this process.

I can't let our daily volume increase forever, so I need to add an additional term to this.

- $v_{max}$ = maximum number of emails allowed to send per day

So my formula would then become

$$V = \sum_{n=1}^d \min(v_0 r^{n-1}, v_{max})$$

When I use the above process to find an ideal ratio ignoring the maximum value, the schedule that I come up with takes too long and I have to manually adjust the ratio until I find one that works well with the additional constraint. Thus, I'd like to adjust my process so that I can identify an ideal ratio for campaigns where $v_{max}$ is relevant.

However, I'm a bit stuck. I'm not really sure how to formulize the summation from above, but I'm pretty sure the result would not be differentiable across the entire domain of this problem. Thus, I don't think that Halley's method will hold up for solving the whole problem. But is there a way to break this problem down more so that it is more tenable?

My best guess so far is that I need to figure out what the minimum number of maximum volume days in the schedule will be, and then use my existing solution to find the ideal ratio to get to the maximum volume by that day. But I'm still stuck on how to do that. Alternatively, I might need to revise how I'm modeling this schedule so that there is a differentiable equation that increases geometrically up to a maximum value.

So, to summarize, what would be the best way to find $r$ in my final summation formula if all other values are known? Is that formula even the right approach to this problem?

---

Just a couple things to note. I'm not going to be searching for a value if the best ratio is $\le 1$ nor will I be searching for a value if the schedule is impossible. So it is safe to assume that a valid value exists, and it will be greater than 1.

Comment: Here I have a plot that depicts upper and lower bounds for the number of days that you will need to send $v_{\textrm{max}}$ emails. $r$ is on the $x$-axis. I can explain this a little more in an answer if you like, but usually we determine the number of days exactly. $https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9elbx2laor

Comment: Thank you @JosephHarrison, but I'm not quite sure that it's addressing the crux of my question. It might be a bit clearer if I just give the problem statement without my attempts at a general solution. I have to send a total of 32,000,000 emails ($V$) over a period of 30 days ($d$). On the first day, I will send 2,500 emails ($v_0$). On any given day, I can send a maximum of 4,000,000 emails ($v_{max}$). What is the lowest ratio ($r$) that my daily volume should increase by that would allow me to send all of these emails within the given constraints?

Comment: The cutoff does mean you're not going to be able to do it with just calculus. Are you willing to do some programming? If so, code up the function $S(r)$, which is the number of emails sent in thirty days with a ratio of $r$. Then you want to find the minimal $r$ such that $S(r) \ge 32$k, which to should be able to find by the bisection method.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC. I am a software engineer, and the source of this problem is in the application that I've written for scheduling these email campaigns, so writing that method is definitely an option. I have one written that gives the number of days to complete a send given the other parameters, but it does make sense to write one for calculating volume that can be sent over a time frame (not just for this problem, but also as it is not an uncommon question). And yes, the bisection method does look like it should work if I define the function. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, a closed solution is always nice, but unless you're going to be calculating this thousands of times each second, the bisection method should be plenty quick enough. Good luck.